# Communication between 2 excel workbooks that opened from different PC

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiples excel workbooks that will be stored in a share drive and each of them will be opened from different PCs on the same time.

ie:
wb1 open from PC1.
wb2 open from PC2.
wb3 open from PC3.
...

Users will update value in cell A1 for each workbook from different PCs. And there will be a main workbook which store the value from each workbooks.
After users updated the value, I want to create a "send" button on each excel workbook to send the value to the main workbook and the main workbook will display the value from different workbooks once user click on the "send" button.
Also, I want to have a "revise" button at the main workbook. When the button is clicked, the values in cell A1 will be cleared and cell A2 will show "Please Revise" for all workbooks.

Is this possible? As all the workbooks are opened at the same time from different PC.

Comment: wb1-3 could write to the "main" workbook as long as it's not open.  The main workbook couldn't write to wb1-3 if the 3 users have those workbooks open.

Comment: You would be much better off using a database for this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, what you are asking for is not possible with current Office editions.  At my previous job we had Excel files on a shared drive that were accessed everyday by multiple computers/users.  One user cannot make edits to an Excel file while it is in use by another user.

If you want multiple users to be able to make edits to a live document at the same time, you might try Google sheets instead.  They have an application very similar to Excel that will probably support what you are trying to do.